Is there any working way to convert nvarchar data type to time data type?
I have two columns in my table: open, close of the nvarchar data type. They have values like this '10:50:PM'. they're supposed to be of the time data type.
I cannot perform any time-related queries on the columns. I've tried casting, converting, updating and altering the columns but it didn't work. It keeps throwing the error message: conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

We don't know what different "formats" of "times" you actually have in this column. Please provide a list. Also tag the RDBMS you use.

10:50:PM is not even a proper time format.

Probably if you put 10:50:00.000 PM, it will work.

I did not create the table nor did I insert the values into the table manually. It was a CSV file I loaded into the database. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

SQL can be weird about this: if there are ANY rows in the entire table that don't convert properly, you can get this error, even if the rows are excluded by a WHERE clause. The database often finds it more efficient to do the conversion on every row first, and apply a WHERE clause conditional expression filter after.

@IfeomaOgbodo As already mentioned, you need to tell us what data you have in this column (list all possible cases how the "time" is "formatted" there), otherwise it's impossible to help.

SQL expects time strings that are being imported to be in a specific format to allow for casting or converting into a TIME data type. The values in your columns ('10:50:PM') are not in a valid time format because the correct format for AM/PM time should be 'hh:mm:ss AM/PM'.
You either need to correct your format in the csv file you're importing from, or re-format your columns in SQL after importing.
You could use the STUFF function to insert a space before the AM/PM, then the time string becomes '10:50:00 PM'.
UPDATE tableName
SET Open = STUFF(Open, LEN(Open) - 1, 0, ' '), 
    Close = STUFF(Close, LEN(Close) - 1, 0, ' ');


I believe the seconds are optional.

I had to manually change the data in Excel then imported the flat file to SQL. It showed the data type as TIME, so everything works alright..
